# making Home brew cider

Tags: fermentation

HI I am making a home brew mixed fruit cider (bulldog brews) I have followed the instructions and after a couple of days of fermenting I got a little frothing but after 7 days not much happening on top and tried to take a gravity reading but thermometer just sank to bottom. is there anything i can do with it now or is it ruined was going to leave it another 7 days but dont know whether i should stir it or add more yeast.

thanks 
kevin statter

Comment: does the fact the Thermometer sink to the bottom mean the cider is not going to be very strong in strength.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ciders don't really get a krausen head like beer, not enough proteins.

If your hydrometer completely sank, then the gravity is far below its limits usually 0.990 which means it's very dry and has attenuated well.

Taste it and go from there.

Comment: Agreed, the krausen usually lasts less than 24 hours.  I made one cider where a lot of bubbles kept blowing through the airlock for four days.  I suspect it was due to crab apples having been boiled - setting the pectin.